# How to enable on screen keyboard with lxdm?

Tags: arch-linux, lxde

I use a touch screen PC (archlinux + lxde).
I want to login with lxdm and enter password with [florence](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html). I tried to add `/usr/bin/florence` in `/etc/lxdm/LoginReady` but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Tried `PreLogin` instead of `LoginReady` (wild guess)?  (A quick fix might be [`autologin=someuser`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDM#Autologin).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking into this - and I tried the same thing: created `/etc/lxdm/LoginReady` from scratch, `chmod +x`-ed it, and inserted a `logger` statement in the script. The logger message does appear in `/var/log/syslog` - however, neither `onboard` nor `xvkbd` can start (and they can break the logger message too).

It turns out, this maybe is not down to `lxdm`, but to `lightdm` - in particular, `lightdm-gtk-greeter` on my device (see also [Is it possible to configure LightDM to load Caribou for the on screen keyboard, replacing onboard? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66128/is-it-possible-to-configure-lightdm-to-load-caribou-for-the-on-screen-keyboard) and [Customising the LightDM GTK Greeter | Arcticdog's Kennel](http://arcticdog.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/customising-the-lightdm-gtk-greeter/)).

Somebody apparently made a patch for Arch, and posted it at [Bug #905809 “PATCH lightdm-gtk-greeter on screen keyboard suppor...” : Bugs : LightDM GTK+ Greeter](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm-gtk-greeter/+bug/905809); unfortunately the Ubuntu folks didn't seem to be interested.

But in any case, it seems one has to patch all the way down to C code, which is rather unfortunate...